# Is there a way to make overriding host-restricted declarations work in the presence of hostname canonicailzation in SSH config?

Tags: ssh

I like security, so my SSH config is set to insist on modern MACs by default. But my company which has a few rather old servers on its intranet, which don't support those MACs. So for those, i have an exception. I also like to be able to refer to servers by their unqualified hostname when SSHing, so i have configured hostname canonicalisation.

My SSH config looks something like this:

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains intranet.initech.com

Host oldserver.intranet.initech.com
        MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1

Host *
        MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
```

If i `ssh newserver.intranet.initech.com`, i connect using the modern MACs. If i `ssh oldserver.intranet.initech.com`, i connect using the old MAC. If i `ssh newserver`, i connect using the modern MACs. But if i `ssh oldserver`, then:

```
Unable to negotiate with 10.93.100.37 port 22: no matching MAC found. Their offer: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,[...]
```

Why? `ssh -v` tells the tale:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/tanderson/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/tanderson/.ssh/config line 30: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Canonicalized hostname "oldserver" => "oldserver.intranet.initech.com"
debug1: Re-reading configuration after hostname canonicalisation
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/tanderson/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/tanderson/.ssh/config line 20: Applying options for oldserver.intranet.initech.com
debug1: /home/tanderson/.ssh/config line 24: Applying options for *.intranet.initech.com
debug1: /home/tanderson/.ssh/config line 30: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
```

What is happening? Well, as the documentation says:

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.

And:

> CanonicalizeHostname
>
> If this option is enabled, then the configuration files are processed again using the new target name to pick up any new configuration in matching Host and Match stanzas.

So the stuff from `Host *` will *always* be applied in preference to any host-specific configuration for a canonicalized hostname.

If i've understood this correctly, it seems to me that hostname canonicalization is basically broken, or at least severely hobbled.

Is there any way to work around this?

I am using OpenSSH_7.6p1, because i am on Ubuntu 18.04.6.